# How to use awk to add multiple lines after pattern

Tags: linux, bash, awk, tcp

I have a situation where Im trying to use use awk to find a pattern and add 10 lines of content right after pattern is found. i tried to work with below but does not work

contents on input iptable.txt file:

```
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

output of iptables.txt should look like

```
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

awk function executed:

```
awk '/--dport 22 -j ACCEPT/{print $0 RS 
"-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT"
"-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT"
"-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT"
} 1' > tmp && mv tmp /home/user/iptables.txt
```

In nutshell what I'm trying to accomplish is when I execute above awk command, it should append the iptable.txt file with line dport 20, 21 and 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the repetitive nature of your input, you could do something like:

```
awk '/--dport 22 -j ACCEPT/ {n=$12; for(i=0; i<=10; i++) {$12=n++; print} next}1' input
```

On the other hand, if your input is not so repetitive, `sed` is better suited for this.  If the 10 lines you want to add are in the file named `new`, just do:

```
sed '/--dport 22 -j ACCEPT/rnew' input
```

The command `r` causes sed to read in the named file after any line that matches the pattern.  If for some reason you don't want to read lines in from a different file, you can use:

```
sed '/--dport 22 -j ACCEPT/a\
first line of new content\
2nd line of new content
' input
```

Comment: Thanks William - i tried sed before trying awk. sed complains about  '-' (dashes) and when i try to escape the \, then it complains about '\'.

Comment: @GanSe Can you show exactly what you tried that sed complained about?  And which version of sed.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
$ awk '
{ print }
/--dport 22 -j ACCEPT/ { print \
"-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT" ORS\
"-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT" ORS\
"-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT"
}
' file
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

or:

```
$ awk -v block='-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT' '
{ print }
/--dport 22 -j ACCEPT/ { print block }
' file
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion - find is not supposed to be a command (anubhava thought so, so he edited it as a command)! What i meant was find a pattern that matched -dport 22 and add rest of the lines block right under it - it should make an permanent edit with line block to the iptables.txt.

Comment: thank you Ed - appreciate it, it only prints on command shell but it does not append those three lines on the actual iptable.txt file. Reason i need to append to that particular file is im planning to run a shell scripts to update different other settings and also update this particular file. Is it even possible using awk function on shell script ?

Comment: @GanSe - your terminology is confusing. What I have posted above is not an awk function, it's an awk script. When you execute it that it IS an awk script being used in a shell script. With any UNIX command, `cmd`, to write back to the original file you just do `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file`. With GNU awk 4.0 and newer you can instead, to save typing a couple of characters, do `awk -i inplace 'script' file`, and with GNU sed you can do `sed -i 'script' file`. Hope that makes sense, if not feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: @GanSe I see you unaccepted my answer. Did it not work for you after all?

Comment: your worked as well - i accepted both your and William's answer. sed was easier incorporate in the script and i used that one. I just noticed when i accepted his answer, yours got unaccepted. How do i accept both ?